# return an object from a function that was put together my promises in that function

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose, promise

I create an object using promises but I cant return the object.
`console.log("pageStuff inside ", pageStuff)` consoles the desired object but I can't figure out how to return it from the pageStuff function.

```
function pageStuff(incoming){
    //pass in comp1
    var pageStuff = {}
    Reviews.find({companyName : incoming, vote : "down"}).count().exec()
    .then(function(returnedDown){
        pageStuff.downVotes = returnedDown;
    })
    .then(function(){
         return Reviews.find({companyName : incoming, vote : "up"}).count().exec()
    })
    .then(function(returnedUp){
        pageStuff.upVotes = returnedUp;
    })
    .then(function(){
        return Reviews.find({companyName : incoming}).count().exec();
    })
    .then(function(totalReviews){
        pageStuff.totalReviews = totalReviews
        pageStuff.voteResult = pageStuff.upVotes - pageStuff.downVotes;
        if(pageStuff.voteResult > 0){
            pageStuff.voteResult = "+" + pageStuff.voteResult;
        }

    }) 

    .then(function(){
        Reviews.aggregate([
            {$match : {companyName : incoming } },
            {$unwind : "$statements"},
            {$group : {
                _id : "$statements.question",
                result : {$avg  : "$statements.result"}
            }}
        ]).exec(function(err, doc){
            if(err) throw err;
            doc.forEach(function(e){
                e.result = Math.round(e.result * 10) /10
            })
            // console.log("doc: "  , Array.isArray(doc) )
            pageStuff.statements = doc;
            console.log("pageStuff inside ", pageStuff)

        })

    })       
     .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
    })  

    return pageStuff;        

}
```

using it gives me an empty `{}`.

I have a feeling it's an asynchronous problem but I don't know how to solve it.

`console.log("pagestuff ::::  ", pageStuff("comp1"))`

Comment: a var inside a function with the same name is not really a good idea (pageStuff), besides that, your function returns a value synchronously before any of the asynchronous functions really start, let alone end - so, you're right, it's an asynchronous thing, and since Promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous, you'll need to rethink what you doing and stop trying to turn asynch to synch because you can't do that

Comment: just put a return before `Reviews.find` - then your code will return a promise, when you call your function, use `.then` as you would with any promise - however, you will need to rewrite your function a little bit to successfully return the value you need

Comment: I did what you said about putting the `return` what part should I change in my code . `pageStuff("comp1")
        .then(function(returnedData){
            console.log("returnedData " , returnedData)
        })` gives me undefined

Comment: prehaps return in front of `Review.aggregate` - it's odd, you seem quite comfortable using promises within the function you wrote, yet you struggle to return the promise you need from that function

Answer (score 0):

Promises are asynchronous and `return` is for synchronous values.

Some possibilities:

- Don't return the value you are interested in. Return the promise instead. The caller can do what they need to do in a `.then()` on the promise it gets back.
- If, for example, this is a library where you don't want to leak promises out to things that are using it, then still don't return the value. Instead, emit an event in a `then()` clause when you have the data and send the data as an argument to the event handler. The library user should add a handler for the event on the object that is emitting it and handle the data inside the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I made it so that the whole function returns a promise. and then

and then I called the function that returned the promise
and I got the result. Thanks for your help guys.

`pageStuff("comp1")
        .then(function(returnedData){
            console.log("returnedData " , returnedData)
        })`

```
function pageStuff(incoming){
    //pass in comp1
    var returnPageStuff = {}
   return  Reviews.find({companyName : incoming, vote : "down"}).count().exec()
    .then(function(returnedDown){
        returnPageStuff.downVotes = returnedDown;
    })
    .then(function(){
         return Reviews.find({companyName : incoming, vote : "up"}).count().exec()
    })
    .then(function(returnedUp){
        returnPageStuff.upVotes = returnedUp;
    })
    .then(function(){
        return Reviews.find({companyName : incoming}).count().exec();
    })
    .then(function(totalReviews){
        returnPageStuff.totalReviews = totalReviews
        returnPageStuff.voteResult = returnPageStuff.upVotes - returnPageStuff.downVotes;
        if(returnPageStuff.voteResult > 0){
            returnPageStuff.voteResult = "+" + returnPageStuff.voteResult;
        }

    }) 

    .then(function(){
        Reviews.aggregate([
            {$match : {companyName : incoming } },
            {$unwind : "$statements"},
            {$group : {
                _id : "$statements.question",
                result : {$avg  : "$statements.result"}
            }}
        ]).exec(function(err, doc){
            if(err) throw err;
            doc.forEach(function(e){
                e.result = Math.round(e.result * 10) /10
            })
            // console.log("doc: "  , Array.isArray(doc) )
            returnPageStuff.statements = doc;
            console.log("returnPageStuff inside ", returnPageStuff)

        })
       .then(function(){
             return returnPageStuff
         })    
    })      

     .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
    })  


}
pageStuff("comp1")
    .then(function(returnedData){
        console.log("returnedData " , returnedData)
    })
```